# Box appears somewhere out of the screen/brwoser-window - how to solve?

Tags: css, center

I use the following css for a modal box that is hidden first and is shown, when the user clicks a link. It should appear in the middle of the screen. The problem is, when I first scroll down the website and then click the link, the box appears somewhere out of the screen/brwoser-window and is not visible. How to correct the css, so that the box always apperas in a visible area?

```
.modal {  
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `fixed` instead of `absolute` this should fix the issue

```
.modal {  
  position:fixed;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `position:fixed;` instead of  `position:absolute;`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).